# how to update num2str in figure window without overwriting

Tags: matlab-figure

I am currently making a game and need the score to get updated in while loop.
Every time the score gets updated in figure, it overwrites on top of previously written text making it blur.

The code goes something like this:

```
score=score+100
text(90,105,num2str(score));

h=text(80,105,'SUN');
 set(h,'color','r');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the handle of the original text box, then update its 'String' property. Instead you keep creating a new text box on top of the old one.

Don't have access to matlab right now but I think something like this should work:

```
% first time you report score! create a text object; call it's handle "scoreBoard"
scoreBoard = text(x,y,num2str(score));

% something happens and we have new score:
set(scoreBoard, 'String', num2txt(score)); % update the string property of scoreBoard
```

Alternatively you could delete the old object and create a new one. I suspect the method I gave above is slightly more efficient though.